# !hasFocus to be triggered after I focus on that Edittext (Android)

Tags: java, android

I need to show the error label after I clicked the Edittext.
Example, at the start of the activity, error labels shouldn't display.
Of course the focused edittext is the edtFirstName, if i click edtLastName and leave edtFirstName blank, it should display the error message. Same as edtLastName. My problem is at the very beginning, error label of edtLastName already display its error label "must not be empty". It already call onFocusChange even at the start of the activity because the focus is at the edtFirstname. how can i fix it? i want to do what google add account on android does.

```
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_signup, container, false);

        edtFirstName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName);
        edtLastName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtLastName);

        tilFName = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tilFName);
        tilLName = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tilLName);

        edtFirstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        edtLastName.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

then

```
 @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        boolean flag = false;

        // First Name
        if (!edtFirstName.hasFocus())
        {
            if (edtFirstName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                tilFName.setError("Must not be empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                tilFName.setError(null);
            }

        }

        if (!edtLastName.hasFocus()) // this is triggered at the start of the activity. 
        {

            if (edtLastName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                tilLName.setError("Must not be empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                tilLName.setError(null);
            }

        }
```

Is there an appropriate code for LostFocus?

EDIT::
[This is what happening after starting the app. I'm not tapping anything. The code already called onFocusChange at the startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNZxe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem after hours of trying

```
 edtFirstName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           edtFirstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                   if (!edtFirstName.hasFocus()) {
                       if (edtFirstName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                           tilFName.setError("Must not be empty.");
                       } else {
                           tilFName.setError(null);
                       }
                   }

               }
           });

            return false;
        }
    });

    edtLastName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edtLastName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    if(!edtLastName.hasFocus()) {
                        if (edtLastName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            tilLName.setError("Must not be empty.");
                        } else {
                            tilLName.setError(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Maybe I have to shorten the code because I have other edittexts waiting. lol. Thanks to your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `Activity`'s parent `XML` layout container:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

ie if you are using `RelativeLayout` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.activities.SampleActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
edtFirstname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (!hasFocus) {
          //do validation here
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need to call onFocusChange after I clicked that Edittext (Example I click edtLName, the I will click another edittext, that is the time that onFocusChange should be triggered and display the error message that edtLName must not be empty.) The problem is, Im not yet tapping edtLName yet it display the error message already.

Answer (score 0):

See my solution. You need to set requestFocus with a delay. A code sample is if you scroll at my profile.